# How to use Headlines in SalesForce Community?

Tags: community, community-builder, headline-component

I got the Help link(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_headline.htm&type=0) from SalesForce. However I did not understand how to set page type , and display articles and topics.I typed 'article' in page type and it did not display any article over there.Can anybody explain how to use all features in Headline component in community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page Type is optional and works only on corresponding standard pages. For example, if you are dragging Headline component on Article Detail page and setting Page Type as "article" and Unique Id as "{!urlName}" then it would work and shows the desired output; otherwise setting page type as "article" on other pages would do nothing.

[image]

Same applies for Topic and Discussion as well. Hope you understand now.

**If everything is setup correctly but still, it renders blank value then it's salesforce issue and check with salesforce support.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for this information .I was adding headline in Home page of community that's why it was not pulling any data. Thank you . However, at least using banner text can I be able to give links of articles to end users? so that they can go through it?